# pass data from fragment to activity by strartActivityforResult()

Tags: java, android

My app show activity .When user press button ,the app will go to fragment -there's 7 fragment- .The user will press button from one of the fragments .After that the app pass String and integer values to the activity .The app will open the activity .
I tried to go to from Activity to fragment by startActivityforResult() ,it work .Then I tried to send data from the fragment to the activity ,the app stopped .

In activity

```
       Intent a =new Intent("android.intent.action.DEFAULT");
                startActivityForResult(a,1);

  }

  @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode ==1)
    {

        newnamem =data.getExtras().getString("name");
        newcm=data.getExtras().getInt("calory");
        return;

    }
   }
```

In fragment

```
   Intent a = new Intent(getActivity(),main.class);
            a.putExtra("calory", Content.Mil001.calory);
            a.putExtra("name", Content.Mil001.meal);
            getActivity().fnish();
```

Comment: What error you get when app crashes?

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods I use.

- Implement interface - Create an interface with getter and setter methods(callback methods). And in your activity implement the interface and call those methods.
- Using public methods - In your activity, create public getter and setter methods.

  Example: getActivity().getCalory(), getActivity().setCalory(args)
- Use EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus